# javafx tablecolumn setcellvaluefactory function

Tags: java, javafx

I had read many tutorial on tableview all of the tutorial on the internet i think are just copying and pasting without explaining actually how it's done my question is about tablecolumn.setCellValueFactory() function

Q1 - I know that the cell value is what the cell value of the column will have so what is the definition of the word factory here ?

```
class Data{
private String Name; }
TableColumn NameColumn = new TableColumn("Name");
NameColumn.setCellValueFactor(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Name"));
```

Q2 - Here we have created anew object of the PropertValueFactory class my question here is how this will access the Name property without even giving the class name ? or how this will know that this Name property from the Data class 
i wish if my question here is understandable

Q3 - Need to know why we actually use this function.
Thanks for your time and effort and i wish if i was writing my questions well.

Comment: Q1: A factory is an object that creates (or provides) other objects. In this case, it provides properties to the cells in the column. Q2: fully explained in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html). Q3: So the cell knows what value it is supposed to display.

Comment: Q2: Your `TableView` contains items. Every object provides a `getClass` method. Using the `Class` this method returns reflection is used to identify and call the appropriate method. (Hint: lacking *any* methods this won't work for the `Data` class.) Q3: A table usually contains multiple columns that display different "parts" of a item. `cellValueFactory` is used to get the appropriate "part" from the item.

Comment: unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them